# how to store data in arrays, use functions for

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to save data into an array using the for function. the following script is used:

```
int[] U;
int k = 0;

String ukecil = i.getStringExtra("ukecil");
String ubesar = i.getStringExtra("ubesar");

int ukk = Integer.parseInt(ukecil);
int ukb = Integer.parseInt(ubesar);

for (int j=ukk; j<=ukb; j++){
  U[k]= j;
  k++;
}

tx_uk1.setText(U[0]);
tx_uk2.setText(U[1]);
tx_uk3.setText(U[2]);
```

then I want to display data in text view.
but there is an error which is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
```

this section error:

```
U[k]= j;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the array.

```java
int[] U=new int[size];
```

If you want dynamic size, use ArrayList.

```java
ArrayList<Integer> U = new ArrayList<Integer>();
U.add(k++,j); //index,element
```

Comment: where do I save this code ?, and is there any part of the code above that needs to be removed?

Comment: Nope.. No removals. If using array method then replace that line only. If using arraylist method. replace int[] U with first line of array list and U[k]=j; and k++; with second line.

Comment: I tried using an array with size 6, but an error length of 6 index 6. I tried an arraylist error String resource ID # 0x18.

tx_uk1.setText (U.get (0));

Comment: try `tx_uk1.setText (U.get (0)+"");`

Comment: I have found a solution. I use : tx_uk1.setText(String.ValueOf(U.get(0));

Comment: Upvote & Accept Answer if this helped you. Thank You.

Comment: how do I check the value of an empty array ?, in php using this: If (empty($U[0])){}

Comment: You cannot check the value of an empty variable. using `empty` function, you can check if the array is empty.

Comment: fine thank you, is your answer, i choose check correct?

Comment: Yes... Thank you

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709547/how-to-check-whether-the-array-element-is-empty-and-provide-a-value-if-it-is-em

Comment: That question was deleted!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full code

```
ArrayList<Integer> U = new ArrayList<>();
int k = 0;

String ukecil = i.getStringExtra("ukecil");
String ubesar = i.getStringExtra("ubesar");

int ukk = Integer.parseInt(ukecil);
int ukb = Integer.parseInt(ubesar);

for (int j=ukk; j<=ukb; j++){
     U.add(k++,j);//Updated
}

tx_uk1.setText(U.get(0)+"");
tx_uk2.setText(U.get(1)+"");
tx_uk3.setText(U.get(2)+"");
```

Hope this helps.......

Comment: @EgaSuhandianto Oh! _Upvote_ & _Accept Answer_ if this helped you. Thank You.

Comment: Error java lang, index 1 size 0.